# Image 2D Real Cepstrum with DFT, Is `ifftshift` Needed?

Tags: image-processing, dft, frequency-domain, 2d, cepstral-analysis

This is my testing image, it is taken from the paper [Image Restoration for Linear Local Motion-Blur Based on Cepstrum](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6457042):

[image]

I tried to transform it into its real cepstrum domain with this simple MATLAB code:

```
cepstrum_img=ifft2(log(1+abs(fft2(img(:,:,1)))));
imshow((abs(cepstrum_img)))
```

But my result is very weird: The maximum is not at the center of image, they are at the 4 corners. And here is the zoomed-in picture with the  maximum at the left top corner:

[image]

But the result in [this paper](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/articleDetails.jsp?arnumber=6457042) is like this:

[image]

The maximum is actually at the center!!

As I didn't do any `fftshift` ,  I don't think I need to do any `ifftshift`.

- This makes me so confused. Is there something wrong with my code?
  or my understanding about 2D real cepstrum with DFT?

**UPDATE 1:** *Why do I think that* `fftshift` *or* `ifftshift` *is not needed here*.

For a length-$N$ sequence $x[n]$, you do an $N$-point DFT. You will get another length-$N$ sequence $X[n]$. The first element of the resulting sequence is corresponded to the zero frequency. Then we do `fftshift` to the resulting length-$N$ sequence, and we get a third length-$N$ sequence $X'[n]$, because we want to make the center (may not be at the center if $N$ is even) of the element in $X'[n]$ corresponded to the zero frequency.

- The question is how can you get the original  $x[n]$ with IDFT?

$\textrm{IDFT}(X[n])$ is right. $\textrm{IDFT}(X'[n])$ is wrong.

Check this MATLAB code:

```
% the original sequence
x=1:8
% this will give you the original sequence
ifft(fft(x))
% but this won't
ifft(fftshift(fft(x)))
% anyway, the amplitude is the same.
```

The case would be the same for images and `fft2` & `ifft2`. i.e.this will get you the original `img`:

```
 ifft2(fft2(img))
```

And if the cepstrum is defined as

$$C=\mathcal F^{-1}\left\{\ln\left(\lvert \mathcal F\left\{I(x,y)\right\}\rvert\right)\right\}$$

Where $I$ = `img`. This is something like transforming from Fourier domain back to the spatial domain.

**UPDATE 2:** *I found where I am wrong..*

When the papers are saying

> The Cepstrum (Calculated with FT) has the maximum at the center

I misunderstood it as

> The Cepstrum calculated with DFT & IDFT has the maximum at the
> center

If the Cepstrum above is really calculated with Fourier transform, the Cepstrum will be with the maximum at the origin. That means if I calculate this with DFT & IDFT,the maximum should be at the corners. The same as FT vs DFT, I have assumed the Cepstrum calculated with DFT should have its maximums at the center. That's where I am wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have image in the spatial domain, in order to calculate its DFT transform you should use `fft`.
Once you have its DFT in order to get back to the spatial domain use the function `ifft`.

Either way, the DFT transform gives you the data in the [0, 2pi] axis.
Use `fftshift` to move it into the [-pi, pi] domain as seen in the paper.

Good Luck.

#### MATLAB Code

This code worked for me:

```
mInputImage = imread('3.png');
mInputImage = double(mInputImage) / 255;
mInputImage = mean(mInputImage, 3);

mImageDft = (fft2(mInputImage));

mImageDft = log(1 + abs(mImageDft));

mImageCepstrum = abs(fftshift(ifft2(mImageDft)));

mImageCepstrum = mImageCepstrum / max(mImageCepstrum(:));

figure();
imshow(mImageCepstrum);
```

Enjoy...

Comment: thank you @Drazick. But I have used both `fft2` and `ifft2` in my codes. The Real cepstrum is defined as $cepstrum=F^{-1}(log|F(I(x,y))|)$ . So I think there's no need to use ifftshift or fftshift.

Comment: @alexyangfox, Have a look at my code. It worked for me (Namely, the function maximum was centered).

Comment: Thank you very much.. It really works..But  I am wondering  whether the maximum should really be at the center.

Comment: Thank you very much again . Yes,You are right.When the papers are saying `The Cepstrum (Calculated with FT) has the maximum at the center`,I misunderstood it with `The Cepstrum calculated with DFT & IDFT has the maximum at the center`